# flv thumbnail using ffmpeg asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ffmpeg, sample

I am trying to find a working sample on how to generate a thumbnail from a flv file using ffmpeg and asp.net & VB.net.  I am uploading a pre-encoded flv so I do not have to generate the video file, just the thumbnail.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: http://www.google.com

Comment: Win32 apps that use ffmpeg or MEncoder/MPlayer are just starting them as a new process (ie old `Shell`).  That is, they cannot be referenced in a  project.  So, find out what the command line parms are for 'take snapshot from location hh:mm:ss" and send that to ffmpeg.